# Virtual backgrounds for any videoconferencing or webcam application

Tags: windows, webcam, web, conferencing

Is it feasible in **Windows** to enable (i.e. force) the use of a *custom* **virtual background**  (via **software**) for **any** (**all**) videoconferencing applications that need to access to a webcam, for a **webcam**? (either screen-embedded front-facing, or **external**).

Or would that depend on the manufacturer of the hardware (e.g. laptop and webcam).

By virtual background I am referring to the ability of customizing the background on a video call so that people can see you as you look, but you can e.g. use a static or animated media for the rest of the background. E.g. [this feature](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/microsoft-teams-now-lets-you-use-custom-backgrounds-during-video-calls/) supported from Microsoft Teams, or [this one](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/210707503-Virtual-Background) from Zoom.

Comment: It is very feasible. SnapChat does EXACTLY this.  It shows as a physical webcam to applications like zoom and slack even though it is a filter/wrapper for my REAL cam devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing this under Windows 7 with Open Broadcast Studio with the VirtualCam addon.  (OBS is also available for Mac and Linux, but you need to use some other tool to provide a virtual camera).  I can run a long running youtube video like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGpp1ZPMKlk in the background on any videoconferencing tool. I select the virtualcam as the current camera.  I use a green backdrop and the Chromakey filter in OBS.  Should work with any hardware and any tool that can select from available cameras.